# Does php's file_get_contents ignore file locking?

Tags: php, flock

I have read php's [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#120389) on the 'file_get_contents' function which does not state anything about how 'file_get_contents` behaves with respect to php's file locking. However in the comment section user Chris suggests that

> file_get_contents does not normally respect PHP's flock locking, i.e.
>   advisory locking.
>
> You can workaround this with some extra code to request a shared lock,
>   like...

```
<?php
$tmp = fopen($path, 'rb');
@flock($tmp, LOCK_SH);
$contents = file_get_contents($path);
@flock($tmp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($tmp);
?>
```

which I have tested with success. I have also tested that even though a file has been locked with `flock()` exclusively `LOCK_EX` it was possible to have another php process read the file via `file_get_contents` as the  comment would have suggested.

However, and that is mainly why I ask for information, I have read a webpage titled ["Reading locked files in PHP"](https://ivopetkov.com/b/reading-locked-files-in-php/), which claimed the following with regards to `file_get_contents` and file locking.

> Reading a locked file with file_get_contents()
>
> This is one the worst way to read a file while it is locked and modified, because:
>   - file_get_contents() will return an empty string (like in "")
>   - filesize() will return the actual number of bytes written to the file

I this claim correct? I run some tests, locking a file exclusively and constantly writing to it, while using `file_get_contents` in another php process to read the file and have not experienced the behaviour that as stated above

> file_get_contents() will return an empty string (like in "")

Is it true in general that, php's `file_get_contents` does not care anything about the advisory file locking. 
Also, am I assuming correctly that the claims made in the webpage of the empty string returned by file_get_contents is empty "", is only true if the file is empty, or temporarily empty (while being modified) but not generally empty (only for the reason of the file being `flock()`ed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flock is relatively independent of the file operations, you can even use fopen on a locked file. You as developer are responsible for checking/using flock everywhere you require a lock.

But yes in that regard it's true that `file_get_contents` has no build-in way to acquire a read lock when reading the file. So the workaround would be the way to go.

`file_put_contents` allows you to get a lock for writing though.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, There is nothing to assume that `file_get_contents` would henceforth return *necessarily* an empty "", because of a file lock. Without a file lock the data read via `file_get_contents` might not be reliable maybe (as no concurrent editions might occur) but I should not assume that `file_get_contents` would kind of check a file lock implicitly and return an empty string? (as was indicated in the second resource linked in the question), correct?

Comment: Correct, it _may_ be that the locking results in some strange side effect, but I doubt that.

Comment: I'm just getting to grips with locking myself, (so I cannot claim to be an "expert") but from what I understand, when a file is written out, the file size is set to zero, and pointer set to start of file before the data is written out. If a file_get_content reads the file at the =EXACT= millisecond the other file is writing out (since it ignores the lock) it will see the empty file.