# Can you read a file concurrently in PHP using file_get_contents()?

Tags: javascript, php, database, file

Let's say there are hundreds, or even thousands, of users on your website at the same time.

In the PHP file, there is a `file_get_contents()` which reads a JSON file and displays that to those users.

I have heard that for some people, it may return a `file does not exist` if another user is reading the file.

Is this possible through `file_get_contents()`? Or is it extremely unlikely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does php's file\_get\_contents ignore file locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262971/does-phps-file-get-contents-ignore-file-locking)

Comment: @PetrHejda No.. PHP 8 is out also, that's an old question from 3 years ago

Comment: Read operations don't set the exclusive lock on the file for other processes (unless you'd specify that locking mode manually).

Comment: @PetrHejda, your links are irrelevant.

Comment: You should have no issues with multiple reads, however to reduce i/o operations on a very busy site, I'd recommend looking at in-memory caching e.g. memcache

Comment: @fewjio I agree with your sentiment but as far as I know, voting to close a question doesn't gain you any reputation points.